# How to generate an MP4 with H.265 codec using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, h.265

I want to encode a video file to H.265. The last version of ffmpeg should be support H.265 ([Source](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?85657-FFmpeg-Now-Supports-HEVC-H-265-Decoding)).

However, I could not find any information about the exact command.

I do not know, which library I should indicate after `-vcodec`.

I use the lastest Zeranoe FFmpeg Build (git-c78a416 (2013-10-26)).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

## Background

FFmpeg supports encoding HEVC/H.265 since 2014-2-12 with libx265. Now you can use ffmpeg directly to encode HEVC or use another encoder then manually mux that into .mp4, .mov, or .mkv using FFmpeg.

### Available Encoders

Current H.265/HEVC encoders are:

- [MulticoreWare x265](https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265/wiki/Home)
- [Chinese x265](https://code.google.com/p/x265)
- [DivX HEVC Encoder](http://labs.divx.com/divx265)
- [Kvazaar](http://ultravideo.cs.tut.fi/#encoder)

Only the MulticoreWare and DivX are suggested because of their development time and reliability.

### Two x265's

One confusion is that there are **two** independent projects both named "x265", one by a Chinese college student and is practically dead, and another by a commercial company called MulticoreWare. Although the former started out first, it is practically dead now, and the latter is under active development and is endorsed by VideoLAN (the developer of x264).

### Timeline of FFmpeg HEVC Encoding Support

- 2013-10-12 .mov muxing support added in `53f903b`.
- 2014-02-12 libx265 encoding support added in `bb6b173`.
- 2014-03-09 More complete Matroska muxing support for HEVC added in `38aee64`.
- 2014-03-09 More complete .mov and new .mp4 muxing support added in `9563e67`.

## tl;dr

Anyways, these are a complete set of current possibilities of encoding HEVC in order of my recommendation:

- Directly using MulticoreWare libx265 with FFmpeg. This means with the latest Zeranoe build you can now do this:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i INPUT -c:v libx265 -an -x265-params crf=25 OUT.mov
  # With audio
  ffmpeg -i INPUT -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 OUT.mov
  ```

  Note: FFmpeg builds newer than 2014-03-09 allows you to mux HEVC into .mp4 files now (commit 9563e67):

  ```
  ffmpeg -i INPUT -c:v libx265 -an -x265-params crf=25 OUT.mp4
  ```

  You can also mux it in Matroska (.mkv):

  ```
  ffmpeg -i INPUT -c:v libx265 -an -x265-params crf=25 OUT.mkv
  ```
- Using standalone MulticoreWare x265 and then mux the resulting file with FFmpeg or [MP4Box](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/). This will work with older FFmpeg builds that don't have libx265 support.

  ```
  # Decode input using FFmpeg and encode using x265 using pipe
  ffmpeg -i INPUT -f yuv4mpegpipe -pix_fmt yuv420p - | \
  x265 --y4m -o encoded.265 -

  # Mux the resulting encoded .265 file into an .mp4 or .mov

  # Using ffmpeg: only works with newer builds that support muxing HEVC
  # Muxing to .mp4 supported since 03-09-2014
  ffmpeg -i encoded.265 -c copy out.mp4
  # With audio
  ffmpeg -i encoded.265 -i INPUT -map 0 -map 1:a -c copy out.mp4

  # Using MP4Box
  MP4Box -add raw.265 out.mp4
  # With audio
  MP4Box -add {INPUT}#audio -add raw.265 out.mp4
  ```

  Thanks to @Duvrai.
- Using DivX HEVC Encoder and then mux it.

  The way of using it is similar to using standalone x265 (see above).

**Update:** FFmpeg has HEVC encoding support using MulticoreWare libx265 now.

**Update 2:** FFmpeg now has support for muxing HEVC into mp4 *AND* mov now.

Comment: For those who don't know what the `crf=25` represents in the example commands, here is a CRF guide: http://slhck.info/articles/crf

Comment: To clarify @Programster's comment, the link goes to an x264 guide, but x265 and x264 are very similar in the CRF selection.

Comment: I couldn't find any guide on CRF specifically aimed at h265 but the concept looks constant. I am currently experimenting with the values it recommends (18-28), but do not know if these need to be slightly different for h265.

Comment: @Programster: Yes x265's range is [0-51](https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265/src/ebf2d550938ca50a750e7cc7ee9fa4f34aed80a0/source/x265.cpp?at=default#cl-413). However **default value** is [28](https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265/src/ebf2d550938ca50a750e7cc7ee9fa4f34aed80a0/source/x265.h?at=default#cl-752) instead of 23.

Comment: Not impressed with the quality with preset medium crf=28. File size is smaller, but I can definitely tell the video quality suffers immensely.

Comment: @sunk818, x265 CRF of course has different meaning from x264's CRF. [This graph](https://blogs.gnome.org/rbultje/files/2015/09/vp9-x264-x265-encoding-speed.png) might be of interest in assessing the quality of x265.

Comment: What would help me is ffmpeg default crf value for x265 matching x264 in terms of quality. An equivalency map of quality between x265 and x264 would also help. If x264 crf is 23 for ffmpeg, then what crf value would match that for x265?

Comment: Great answer overall, but missing a critical bit; `-c:v libx265` as it is, the examples above output using x264. For clarity, `ffmpeg -i INPUT -c:a copy -x265-params crf=2 OUTPUT_h265.mp4` was encoding with x264, but `ffmpeg -i INPUT -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=2 OUTPUT_h265.mp4` encoded with x265.

Answer (score 35):

ffmpeg added x265 encoding on 12 February 2014, and mp4 container support on 9 March:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx265 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Note:

- The above command will copy the audio in it's original codec. If that doesn't work, convert the audio to AAC by omitting `-c:a copy` (or replace `copy` with `aac`, `libfdk_aac` or `libfaac` — ordered quality-wise)
- when compiling ffmpeg use `--enable-libx265` (and `--enable-libfdk-aac` or `--enable-libfaac` if needed)

Comment: FFmpeg supports muxing HEVC natively in mp4 since 3-9-2014.

Comment: For some reason the result was green and pink, but when I added `-pix_fmt yuv420p` before the `-c:v`, the result was fine.

Answer (score -4):

Try the current divx encoder. It has build in support for h265:
http://www.divx.com/

(as reported http://jkdigital.de/h265-hevc-divx-praxisbericht/ )

Comment: The question is specifically about using ffmpeg to accomplish this.