# Convert x265 to MP4 or something else compatable for viewing.

Tags: video-conversion

I downloaded some files (a TV series) that use x265.  They will only play on a  computer, not on a dvd using XtoDVD4, not on a flash drive, and not on a newer Sony player or smart TV.  Is there an easy way to convert these files to MP4 or something similar that is compatable? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: [related: How to generate an MP4 with H.265 codec using FFmpeg?](http://superuser.com/q/785528/172747)

Comment: @bummi that's not really related. Apparently he needs to re-encode the files from H.265/HEVC to H.264/AVC (or maybe DivX/XviD, depends on the player/TV).

Comment: MP4 is a container, h265 is a codec. They can (and often do) co-exist. Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)*, a command-line tool, to do this.

Run

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

If the above fails due to audio, use this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

*get the latest nightly or snapshot binary for your platform.